# Updating a column with the results of a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.2

I have the following table in PostgreSQL 9.2 which contains time stamps:

**gid [PK] (bigserial), timestamp_mes (timestamp without time zone), time_diff (interval)**  
1, 2012-01-23 11:03:40, empty
2, 2012-01-23 11:03:42, empty
3, 2012-01-23 11:03:44, empty

I have added a interval column (time_diff) and would like to fill it with time difference values resulting from this query:

```
SELECT timestamp_mes - lag(timestamp_mes, 1) 
over (order by timestamp_mes) as diff
from gc_entretien.trace order by timestamp_mes
```

I have tried the following query to update the time_diff column, with no success:

```
UPDATE gc_entretien.trace set time_diff = 
(SELECT trace.timestamp_mes - lag(trace.timestamp_mes, 1) 
over (order by trace.timestamp_mes) 
from gc_entretien.trace order by timestamp_mes);
```

This results in an error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How should I proceed to update the time_diff column with the values resulting from the time difference query?

Comment: Not sure about the logic of your app, but the select returns possibly more rows which causes error when assigning into single column (like you do in your `UPDATE`)... if the result is in first row returned in your `SELECT`, use `LIMIT 1` to make the assignment possible. Anyway the select doesn't seem to be correctly designed.

Comment: @KamilŠrot - There's a problem with that; because the subquery is (currently) uncorrelated, `LIMIT 1` will just return the top row, period, not one that has anything to do with the current row.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse right, that's why I say it's not correctly designed query. First @jatobat need to create a query returning exactly one value (the one he needs according to the application logic) and then put it as subquery into `UPDATE` query... usual scenario is to use some identifiers/values from the table (resp. row) being updated in the subquery as condition(s) in the subquery `WHERE` clause. But frankly said: I don't understand the logic of the app and even don't wanna to understand it :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with new_values as (
   SELECT gid, 
          timestamp_mes - lag(timestamp_mes, 1) over (order by timestamp_mes) as diff
   from gc_entretien.trace 
)
update gc_entretien.trace as tr
  set time_diff = nv.diff
from new_values nv
where nv.gid = tr.gid;
```

Comment: +1. This looks right to me, and beat me by 4 minutes. Never knew about the existence of `WITH... AS...` until now. Cool. :)

Comment: @MarkAmery: that's called a "common table expression", and since 9.1 this can also be used for DML statements (before that it could only be used for normal SELECT statements - including recursive queries)

Comment: If you are doing this in T-SQL then it seems you cannot alias the update table. If you use the table name explicitly (instead of tr in this case) it would work though.

Comment: @SpencerKershaw: well, the question is tagged `postgresql` so it's obvious this answer won't apply to SQL Server.

Comment: Your answer is extremely useful though for SQL in general, it was exactly what i was looking for. I just figured others may experience the same I did.

Answer (score 7):

You can't directly use a window function in an UPDATE, so you instead need to use it in a sub-SELECT - which you have done. However, the way you've tried to use that sub-SELECT in your UPDATE is not valid syntax. You need to put the sub-SELECT in the FROM clause of your update, as explained by the Postgres docs here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html

The correct syntax for what you want to do is:

```
UPDATE gc_entretien.trace t
SET time_diff = subquery.diff
FROM (SELECT {{SomeUniqueId}}, 
             timestamp_mes - lag(timestamp_mes, 1) over (order by timestamp_mes) as diff
      FROM gc_entretien.trace order by timestamp_mes) AS subquery
WHERE t.{{SomeUniqueId}} = subquery.{{SomeUniqueId}}
```

Obviously, you'll need to substitute in the column name of some unique id that your rows have where I've written `{{SomeUniqueId}}`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are getting this error because your subquery returns multiple result,

I am not able to understand your query so,

I will give you an example to solve it,

```
update table t1 set time_diff= select *your_operation* from table t2 where t1.id=t2.id
```

**Here** :-your_operation means the logic of finding time difference,

Comment: Yes, this is the general form of what he needs to do... perhaps fill out the rest of the query?

Comment: This answer worked for me having a problem with PostgreSQL 9.0.1. Thanks.